# I have created a custom DropDownButton with GetX in Flutter, it throws me error when i wrap with obx and if i remove obx i cannot select from the list

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-dropdownbutton

Custom DropDownButton

```
class CustomDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
PurchasePackageController purchasePackageController =
  PurchasePackageController();
final String hintName;
final List<String> listName;
final void Function(String?)? onChanged;
CustomDropDown(
  {Key? key,
  required this.hintName,
  required this.listName,
  required this.onChanged})
  : super(key: key);

@override
State<CustomDropDown> createState() => _CustomDropDownState();
}

class _CustomDropDownState extends State<CustomDropDown> {
String? selectedValue;

List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> buildDropdownMenuItems(List list) {
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropDownItems = [];
list.forEach((value) {
  dropDownItems.add(DropdownMenuItem<String>(
    value: value,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: colorPrimary),
      ),
    ),
  ));
});

return dropDownItems;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0.h),
  child: InputDecorator(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorPrimary),
      ),
    ),
    isEmpty: true,
    //dropdownvalue == '',
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: Obx(() => DropdownButton<String>(
            iconSize: 30.0.sp,
            iconEnabledColor: colorPrimary,
            hint: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0.h),
              child: Text(
                widget.hintName,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0.sp, color: colorPrimary),
              ),
            ),
            value: selectedValue,
            isDense: true,
            onChanged: (value) => widget.onChanged,
            buildDropdownMenuItems() 
            items: buildDropdownMenuItems(
              widget.listName,
            ),
          )),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

View

```
class LocationView extends GetView<LocationController> {


LocationView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Location'),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        CustomDropDown(
          hintName: "Package Type",
          listName: controller.MDPackageType,
          onChanged: (newValue) =>
              controller.onChangedPackageName(newValue!),
        ),
        CustomDropDown(
            hintName: "Package Name",
            listName: controller.MDPackageType,
            onChanged: (newValue) =>
                controller.onChangedPackageType(newValue!)),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
          child: Column(children: [
            Text(controller.selectedPackageName.value),
            Text(controller.selectedPackageType.value)
          ]),
        )
      ],
    ));
}
```

}

Controller

```
class LocationController extends GetxController {


List<String> MDPackageType = [
'Package Type 1',
'Package Type 2',
'Package Type 3',
'Package Type 4',
];
List<String> MDPackageName = [
'Package Name 1',
'Package Name 2',
'Package Name 3',
'Package Name 4',
];
var selectedPackageType = "Package Type 1".obs;
var selectedPackageName = "Package Name 1".obs;

onChangedPackageType(String value) => selectedPackageType.value = value;
onChangedPackageName(String value) => selectedPackageName.value = value;
}
```

Error

> throw """
> [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
> You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
> If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
> or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
> (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
> If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
> """;
> }

And if i remove obx, i can code is running but i cannot select items frrom the Drop Down Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!!!

Had to change

```
onChanged: (value) => widget.onChanged,
```

to

```
onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = value;
          });
          if (widget.onChanged != null) widget.onChanged!(value);
        },
```

And remove Obx

Comment: You probably want to change Stateful to Stateless widget instead